# android application is crashing

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made an android application in which there is a text and button in first activity  when I click on  button it should go to second activity and view the images in grid view but its not doing that it gives the message it has stopped unexpectedly. Here is the code.

mainactivity:

```
package com.karan.myjigsaw;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void playGame(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

main.xml

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_margin="120dip"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome_note"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_play"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick = "playGame" />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

gameactivity:

```
 public class GameActivity extends Activity {

ImageView image;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //create grid view
    GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);   

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
   gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

}
```

gameactivity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" > 

</GridView>
```

image view adapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 private Context mContext;

// references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.imagesl_01,R.drawable.imagesl_02,
               R.drawable.imagesl_03,R.drawable.imagesl_04,R.drawable.imagesl_05,
             R.drawable.imagesl_06,R.drawable.imagesl_07,R.drawable.imagesl_8,
            R.drawable.imagesl_9};

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
       } else {
           imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    }
```

logcat:

```
08-02 00:24:30.160: D/AndroidRuntime(286): Shutting down VM
08-02 00:24:30.160: W/dalvikvm(286): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.bellurbis.karan.myjigsaw/com.bellurbis.karan.myjigsaw.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at com.bellurbis.karan.myjigsaw.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-02 00:24:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What does logcat show you? can you post logcat here?

Comment: @karan421 Have you mention the activity in your manifest file ?

Comment: You did not seem to have added onClickListener on your Main activity button.

Comment: @VinayKumarjg  I have added logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error:U must setContentView(R.layout.gameactivity) firstly,and secondly to use findViewById(R.id.grid_view)!

Comment: Could you please tell me how you spotted this error(assuming you would have used logcat details)

Answer (score 2):

1. create intent like this

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. and post log message for better understanding of your error.
3. you did not mention any layout in GameActivity

   ```
   public class GameActivity extends Activity {

   ImageView image;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.gameactivity)

      GridView  gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);       
      gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: can you show me gameactivity line 20. and look at my answer and follow those changes you will solve your problem..

Answer (score 1):

You should call super in the ImageAdapter constructor otherwise you can't initialize the BaseAdapter.

Comment: public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }